# MySQL complicated IF statement

Tags: php, mysql

Sure this is easy, but damned if I can get it to work.

Essentially want to do the following: (obviously this isn't valid MySQL)

```
IF config.a = 1

THEN
UPDATE users SET something = 1
WHERE userlevel > 2
```

So there are two tables involved, but no real connection between the config table and the users table.  The config table has two columns, value and setting.  We only want the rest of the query to run if the value of the row with setting "a" has the value "1".  So it is not quite as easy as if there was a specific field we are looking for.

Reason for asking is I need to run this conditionally across several databases as a single query, and this will be a much easier way than PHP connecting to each DB in turn.

Thanks as always for any assistance.

Comment: What does your `config` table look like?

Comment: There's no join between config and users?  Why not just "update users, config set users.something = 1 where config.a = 1 and userlevel > 2" ?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it in a single query, that would be:

```
UPDATE  u.users
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  1 AS r
        FROM    config
        WHERE   setting = 'a'
                AND value = 1
        ) q
SET     u.something = 1
WHERE   u.userlevel > 2
```

But it's one of those cases when you need to do two queries and run (or not run) one after another.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE users u, 
(
 SELECT a FROM config
) c 
SET u.something = 1
WHERE 
    u.userlevel > 2 
AND c.a = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for you.

```
SELECT (
    UPDATE users SET something = 1 WHERE users.id = config.user_id
) AS updated
FROM config
WHERE userlevel > 2 AND config.a = 1
```

This will work if config has the userId, and then, you use that ID in the subquery.